# confused on use of abbreviations for LPTHW ex 39

Tags: python

Here is the code for this example in Learn PYthon The Hard Way:

```
states = {
'Oregon': 'OR',
'Florida': 'FL',
'California': 'CA',
'New York': 'NY',
'Michigan': 'MI'
}

cities = {
'CA': 'San Francisco',
'MI': 'Detroit',
'FL': 'Jacksonville'
}

cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

print '_' * 10
print "NY State has: ", cities['NY']
print "OR State has: ", cities['OR']

print '_' * 10 
print "Michigan's abbreviations is: ", states['Michigan']
print "Florida's abbreviation is: ", states['Florida']

print '_' * 10
print "Michigan has: ", cities[states['Michigan']] #could do cities['MI']
print "Florida has: ", cities[states['Florida']]

print '_' * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
print "%s is abbreviated %s" %(state, abbrev)

print '_' * 10
for abbrev, city in cities.items():
print "%s has the city %s" % (abbrev, city)

print '_' * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
print "%s state is abbreviated %s and has city %s" %(state, abbrev, cities[abbrev])
```

---

I'm confused about the word "abbrev" in these four blocks of code:

```
print '_' * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
print "%s is abbreviated %s" %(state, abbrev)

print '_' * 10
for abbrev, city in cities.items():
print "%s has the city %s" % (abbrev, city)

print '_' * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
print "%s state is abbreviated %s and has city %s" %(state, abbrev, cities[abbrev])
```

I'm especially confused with the last line where it says cities[abbrev].

Can anyone tell me how/why he is using the "for abbrev" statement? - Think I understand this now, but a little clarification would be nice. I'm new to this and only used to for-loops that contain one variable like:

```
fruits = [apples, oranges, grapes]

for fruit in fruits:
  print "A fruit of type: %s" % fruit
```

Lastly, why is worded states.items() and cities.items()? Why is the .items needed, couldn't it just be states() and cities()? I just realized you need the .items due to the fact that we are calling multiple variables from the dict, not just one. Is that correct? Will it always be .items in a case like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [avoid LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints).

> Lastly, why is worded states.items() and cities.items()? Why is the .items needed, couldn't it just be states() and cities()?

Try running `print states.items()` and `print states()` and see what happens. You should always be experimenting with such things before asking others about them.

`for state, abbrev in states.items():` is an abbreviation for:

```
for item in states.items():
    state, abbrev = item  # which means state = item[0], abbrev = item[1]
```

This is called tuple unpacking.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I did run them separately, but stupidly did so after posting- I edited the post to reflect this. As far as avoiding LPTHW- I had to start somewhere, and it's actually taught me a lot. I will be going to Think Python next.

Comment: @Wolverine states.items() returns pairs of keys and values, states() is an error, and iterating directly over just states will only yield the keys.